# Angular 7 reading the first column of an excel file and save it into an array

Tags: angular, typescript, angular7, xlsx

I am trying to upload an excel file, where the first column is an ID column.

I need to take all the IDs and save them into an array to use them later for data management.

I am using `XLSX` library:

```
import {read, write, utils} from 'xlsx';
```

And for the html:

```
<input type="file" value="Upload Excel/CSV file" (change)="upload($event)" accept=".xlsx, .xls, .csv"/>

<button mat-fab color="warn" (click)="read()"><mat-icon color="warn">attach_file</mat-icon>Read Data</button>
```

I started with:

```
read()
{
    const file = new FileReader();
}
```

But I am not able to tell the file reader to read the uploaded file.

**EDIT**

I tried to use the change event of the file input:

```
upload(e)
  {
    let input = e.target;
    for (var index = 0; index < input.files.length; index++) {
        let reader = new FileReader();
        reader.onload = () => {
            // this 'text' is the content of the file
            var text = reader.result;
            console.log(reader.result)
        }

        reader.readAsText(input.files[index]);
    };
  }
```

But the read result is like an encryption.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This answer will work for .csv files :

```html
<input id="file" type="file" accept=".csv" (change)="fileUpload($event.target.files)">
```

```js
fileUpload(files) {
    if (files && files.length > 0) {
        const file: File = files.item(0);
        const reader: FileReader = new FileReader();
        reader.readAsText(file);
        reader.onload = (e) => {
            const res = reader.result as string; // This variable contains your file as text
            const lines = res.split('\n'); // Splits you file into lines
            const ids = [];
            lines.forEach((line) => {
                ids.push(line.split(',')[0]); // Get first item of line
            });
            console.log(ids);
        };
    }
}
```

Comment: Error on `split` as it doesn't exists on type string. And the consoled result is encoded or something.

Comment: Can you share a part of the .csv file? When exporting data from excel to csv format you have to pick UTF-8 as a character set.

Comment: It worked but what if the file was an xlsx and not a csv ?

Comment: Sir, what if the uploaded file is an excel and not a csv

Comment: For .xlsx files I don't know, maybe you could have a look to @Kris' [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55219864/10122791).

Answer (score 2):

You should probably let the library decide how to read the workbook, instead of reading it as if it were text.

I can't test this at the moment, but it could look something like this, using an array buffer:

```
var reader = new FileReader();
reader.onload = function(e) {
    var data = new Uint8Array(e.target.result);
    var workbook = XLSX.read(data, {type:"array"});

    // collect your ID's here
};
reader.readAsArrayBuffer(input.files[index]);
```

Comment: readAsArrayBuffer did the trick for me, using large excel files